# Why I can't see Kotlin example in developer.android.com?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

This [page](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) shows me Java code, if I change it to Kotlin, it still shows Java. Am I missing something or this is error? Android studio tries to convert it but it still doesn't work. Should I search for documentation in different sites?

Comment: The sample code at the top comes from the Javadoc from the source code of the class. They haven’t added alternative Kotlin code to the docs yet. You’ll notice all the function names are in Kotlin format.

Comment: But Kotlin is alive almost 10 years. It's weird that they still haven't added it.

Comment: Only officially supported for two years on Android.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. Now I understand why it's so lack of information about Kotlin. I'll probably go to Java.

Comment: They are moving to make Kotlin the primary language. I wouldn’t switch, but it is worth learning some basic Java syntax so you can read it. Java 8 features like lambdas are very rare in any Android Java code you might see, so you only need to know a few basics to be able to read it if you know Kotlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are still working on converting the documentation examples to kotlin.

> **Do you have Kotlin reference docs for Android APIs?**
>
> Yep! We're working
> to make all Android API documentation available with idiomatic >
> Kotlin references. They're not all ready yet, but you can find links
> to the  available Kotlin references on the Android reference overview.
> If you're looking > for the core Kotlin language references, go to the
> Kotlin standard library reference.

is what it says in the official documentation.

https://developer.android.com/kotlin/faq (scroll down to *Do you have Kotlin reference docs for Android APIs?*)

I also remember reading another article saying the same thing.